# Is this a memory issue with DNN_BACKEND_CUDA and DNN_FRONTEND_CUDA?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/dnn_superres.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <filesystem>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <opencv2/dnn/dnn.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/cuda.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cuda;
using namespace dnn;
using namespace dnn_superres;


int upsample_and_save(DnnSuperResImpl sr,
                      std::filesystem::path file_path,
                      std::filesystem::path save_dir) {
    std::cout<<"We are inside of upsample_and_save!" ;                   
    Mat img = cv::imread(file_path.string()); //Read image
    std::cout<<"We are inside of upsample_and_save and read the image" ;
    Mat img_new ; //Container to store upsampled image
    std::cout<<"We are inside of upsample_and_save and created img_new" ;
    sr.upsample(img, img_new); //Upsample
    std::cout<<"We upsampled" ;

    cv::imwrite((save_dir / file_path.filename()).string(), img_new); //Save upscaled image
    std::cout<<"We wrote the image!" ;
    std::cout<< (save_dir / file_path.filename()).string();
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    // Parameters
    string original_path = "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Upscale/original"; //Path to folder containing original files
    std::filesystem::path upscaled_path = "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Upscale/upscaled"; //Folder to save upscaled images

    std::vector<std::string> models {"lapsrn", "fsrcnn"};
    std::vector<std::string> model_weights {"LapSRN_x8.pb", "FSRCNN_x2.pb"};
    std::vector<int> scale_factors {8,2};

    string model_dir = "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Upscale/models/";
    int model_choice = 1; //CHOOSE MODEL HERE (index in vector starting from 0)
    std::vector<std::string> allowed {".jpg",".png"}; //Allowed image types
    


    string model = models[model_choice]; //Model for dnn_superres
    int scale_factor = scale_factors[model_choice]; //Scale factor
    string model_path = model_dir + model_weights[model_choice]; //Model weights



    DnnSuperResImpl sr; //Module instance
    sr.readModel(model_path); //Read model weights
    sr.setPreferableBackend(cv::dnn::DNN_BACKEND_CUDA);
    sr.setPreferableTarget(cv::dnn::DNN_TARGET_CUDA);
    sr.setModel(model, scale_factor); //Set model and scale
    std::cout<<"We set up OK!";


    for (const auto &file : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(original_path)) { 
        std::cout<<"We are inside of the for loop!";

        if (std::count(allowed.begin(), allowed.end(), file.path().extension())) {
            upsample_and_save(sr, file.path(), upscaled_path);
            std::cout<< "We hit upsample in the for loop!";
        } else {
        std::cout<<"The if statement has failed!"; 
        }


std::cout<< "out of the loop";
return 0;
}
}
```

**The issue I am having**:

If I set the model to FSRCNN_x2.pb by adjusting model_choice to 1, the code works great! This model upscales an image by 2x. However, if I select LapSRN_x8.pb, the code will produce the following output:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Upscale\build\Release> ."C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Upscale/build/Release/upscale.exe"
We set up OK! We are inside of the for loop! We hit upsample in the for loop! We are inside of upsample_and_save! We are inside of upsample_and_save and read the image! We are inside of upsample_and_save and created img_new
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Upscale\build\Release>
```

The code seems to hit the `sr.upsample(img,img_new)` and then completely crash!

I have attempted to fix this by commenting out

```
    sr.setPreferableBackend(cv::dnn::DNN_BACKEND_CUDA);
    sr.setPreferableTarget(cv::dnn::DNN_TARGET_CUDA);
```

And after doing so, it appears that the code works fine. Does anyone know why this is happening?